# Angular - UI.Router not loading component

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to get ui.router to load a component on index.html, through a localhost or otherwise:

index.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-ui-router@0.3.1/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script> <!-- used to route views -->
    <script src="js/components.js"></script>

    <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div> <!-- main content -->
         <ui-view></ui-view>   <!-- this directs ui-router to put the home view here-->
    </div>
```

components.js

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']); //makes a call to the Angular API to create our app, configured with the ui.router plug-in
    //configure our view router
    app.config(function($stateProvider) { 
      //create our different views as objects
      var mainState ={
        name: 'main', //name of the object
        url: '', //url to point to, or that causes this view to be triggered
        component: 'home', //component that works with the data, loads the template
        resolve: { //data to bind to our component
          data: function(Resource) {
            console.log(Resource.test()) //returns "Hello World"
            return Resource.test() 
          }
        }
      }
      //call the states
      $stateProvider.state(mainState); 
    })
    app.service('Resource', function ($http) {
      var service = {
       test: function() {
          return "Hello world"
        }
      }
      return service;
    })
    app.component('home', {
      bindings: { data: '<'}, //make the data we loaded into the view from the factory available to this component
      template: "<p>{{data}}</p>", //this is the html that we will plug our data into
      controller: function () {
        console.log(this) //does not call
      }
    })
```

"Hello world" loads, as does data when I make $http gets through the service. But it does not get passed to the component. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`component` attribute is available from `ui-router@1.0.0`(see [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2627) and in [CHANGELOG.MD](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) - it was added  in `1.0.0-aplpha`) so it's not available `0.3.1`.

Here is working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michal_taborowski/caxbw1am/) (with 1.0.3-beta)

Comment: Ah. That makes complete sense. Thank you.

Comment: So where can we download ui-router 1.x, alpha or beta? I see that [1.0.0-beta.3](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases/tag/1.0.0-beta.3) is out. But how do we get it? Where is the prebuilt minified `.js` file?

Comment: They don't make it easy to download. I found I could get it here: https://npmcdn.com/angular-ui-router@1.0.0-beta.3/release/angular-ui-router.min.js

Comment: I too could not easily find the download. By inspecting their tutorials page (which makes it seem like the "stable" version supports this since their tutorial does...) I found their link: https://unpkg.com/angular-ui-router@1.0.0-beta.3/release/angular-ui-router.js

Comment: @MiTa, are you sure about that? I saw that there is a polyfill for 0.2.18 angular ui-router, unfortunately it does not work at my app, so I was wandering if I am missing something. https://github.com/softsimon/ui-router-route-to-components

Answer (score 0):

By default the data will be applicable on view with `$ctrl` controller alias

```
template: "<p>{{$ctrl.data}}</p>",
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z95UhXhgzryRGnrJw8Vx?p=preview)