# Does UI-Router Resolve Work with Angular 1.5 Components?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

So, UI-router resolves were a thing of beauty in angular 1:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
      resolve:{
          myVarFromResolve: function(){
              return 'test'; 
          }
      }
   })

  controller: function($scope, myVar){
      $scope.myVar= myVarFromResolve;
      if(true){console.log($scope.myVar}; //logs 'test'
  }
```

How do I do the same with an Angular 1.5. component (example below)?

```
export default function FooComponent() {
  let fooComponent = {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'foo.html',
    controller: controller,
    controllerAs: 'foo',
    bindToController: true,
  };

  return landingComponent;
}
```

And the resolve...

```
.state('fooState', {
  parent: 'someParent',
  url: '/fooUrl',
  template: '<foo></foo>',
  resolve:{
       myVarFromResolve: function(){
           return 'test'; 
       }
    }
})
```

I read a [guide](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component) on how to do this, but I don't really understand it. Seems like the functionality isn't fully in place and that's a hack.

Comment: Refer to this question:
 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668477/angular-ui-router-not-loading-component

They have a working example which uses ui-router@1.0.0.  

Are you using ui router 0.3.x by any chance  If so, it won't as per the above link.  Also I am not sure about this working with ES6 at all.  In any case, angular.module('app').component() syntax works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is "Yes, kinda"...

I was given a work-around to this problem by a team member that works for `angular-ui-router  0.2.18` (use `npm list angular-ui-router --depth=0` to check your version quickly). It does work while using ES6 classes.

The work around is based on the fact that there is no (easy/known) way to get the variable passed into the controller, like you would in Angular 1 before component architecture introduced in 1.5. Instead, we create a service method that creates a promise (or returns an http call). Then you simply put the promise in the resolve. The promise method WILL return before the controller loads. So while you do not have a easy to use var, you have the data you need in a service.

```
  resolve: {
    preloadSomeVariableIntoAService: function (MyExampleService) {
      return MyExampleService.presetSomeVariable();
    }
  //Note that 'preloadSomeVariableIntoAService' won't be used anywhere in our case
  }
```

The service could be something like this:

```
export default class MyExampleService {

  constructor( $q ) {
    this.q =  $q;
    this.myVariableFromResolve = undefined;
  }

  presetStreamStatus(){

    var deferred = this.q.defer();

    return $http.get(someUrl).then(response) => {
          this.myVariableFromResolve = response.data;
          deferred.resolve(events);
        });

    return deferred;

  };

};
```

You will then be able to get `myVariableFromResolve` from the service. I am not sure you have to use $q deferred, but it seems to be necessary since I am not simply returning the call but also setting the variable. Not sure. Hope this helps someone.