# Angular UI-Router works with template but not component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I am attempting to use angular-ui-router on an angular 1 project. The issue that I'm running into is that I can get angular-ui-router to work when I specify a template, but not when I specify a component.

For instance, this works:

```
var groceryListRoutes = function($stateProvider) {
    var listOfGroceryLists = {
        name: 'listOfGroceryLists',
        url: '/lists',
        template: '<grocery-list-component></grocery-list-component>',
    };
    $stateProvider.state(listOfGroceryLists);
};
```

However, when I attempt to specify the component, nothing shows up, and no error is given in the console:

```
var groceryListRoutes = function($stateProvider) {
    var listOfGroceryLists = {
        name: 'listOfGroceryLists',
        url: '/lists',
        component: 'groceryListComponent',
    };
    $stateProvider.state(listOfGroceryLists);
};
```

Here is my `grocery-list.module.js`, which register the component and the routs:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-resource';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

import groceryListComponent from './grocery-list.component';
import groceryListAPIService from './grocery-list.service';
import groceryListRoutes from './grocery-list.routes';

import groceryListDetailComponent from './grocery-list-detail.component';

const GroceryListModule = angular.module('groceryList', [
    // Dependencies
    'ngResource',
    'ui.router',
])
    .config(($resourceProvider) => {
        $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
    })
    .factory('groceryListAPIService', groceryListAPIService)
    .component('groceryListComponent', groceryListComponent)
    .component('groceryListDetailComponent', groceryListDetailComponent)
    .config(groceryListRoutes);

export default GroceryListModule;
```

And my `grocery-list.component.js`:

```
import template from './grocery-list.template.html';

import groceryListController from './grocery-list.controller';

const groceryListComponent = {
    template,
    controller: groceryListController,
    controllerAs: 'groceryListCtrl',
}

export default groceryListComponent;
```

And my `packages.json`:

```
{
  "name": "shopping-list",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An app to keep track of your grocery shopping",
  "repository": "https://github.com/thomascothran/shopping_list.git",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "eslint": "eslint"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "eslint": "^3.7.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.3.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-stream": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-resource": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.1.3",
    "ramda": "^0.22.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you have a typo? the variable holding the conifg does not match the one you pass to stateprovider: 
`listOfGroceryLists` =/= `gorceryListDetail`

Comment: @Eric -- sorry, I've corrected it in my question above. I have a number of routes in that file, and I deleted the wrong line when I was paring down my question for stack overflow. I believe the problem is the version of angular-ui-router I have, per Mahesh's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this question: 
[Angular - UI.Router not loading component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668477/angular-ui-router-not-loading-component)

Looks like you are using 0.3.x as per your package.json, which won't work.  Upgrade to 1.0.0 and try please.

> component attribute is available from ui-router@1.0.0(see [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2627) and in [CHANGELOG.MD](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) - it was added in 1.0.0-aplpha) so it's not available 0.3.1

Comment: That was it. I'd gone over the docs for a couple hours and not noticed that support for components is only in the beta version. I updated `packages.json` to get the v.1.0 beta, and it worked. Thanks @Mahesh, that saved me quite a bit of time.