# Angular-ui-router 0.3.2 doesn't work correct with components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

0.3.2 is a new version of ui-router [ui-router releases](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases)

I have tested it and looks like it doesn't work correct. Please take a look this [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/gj3M03abn7j52xV0Bp4J?p=preview). Console output - `Unknown provider: $uiRouterProvider <- $uiRouter`

Comment: Your plunker example is from the ui-router 1.0 tutorials.  Only ui-router 1.0 and above support route to component. Version 0.3.2 does not support it.

Comment: @ChrisT Does 0.3.2 supports routing for components?

Comment: No, it does not officially support routing to components.  You use a route-to-component template like in this comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2793#issuecomment-223764105  or you can try the third party polyfill https://github.com/softsimon/ui-router-route-to-components

Answer (score 2):

We just wrote a comprehensive blog post about components and ui router.  It may help with both your current situation and the future upgrade to ui.router 1.0.

http://blog.aviture.us.com/2017/01/03/ui-routing-to-components-in-angular.html